# Exception while creating TimeSheetEntry in s4sdk

Tags: s4sdk

Currently I am trying to  use the S4/HANA SDK to create `TimeSheetEntries` but I have encountered some problems. 
I am receiving this kind of exception:
`Cannot cast class java.util.HashMap to class com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana.datamodel.odata.namespaces.manageworkforcetimesheet.TimeSheetDataFields`
while I am executing `createTimeSheetEntry` method.
Am I doing something wrong? I attached a simple example how I am using the API and if you could point me in the right direction I would really appreciate your efforts.

```
 public void createHardCodedEntry() throws ODataException {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(2017, Calendar.DECEMBER, Calendar.MONDAY);
    TimeSheetEntry entry = TimeSheetEntry.builder().timeSheetDate(c)
            //.timeSheetIsExecutedInTestRun(false)
            //.timeSheetIsReleasedOnSave(true)
            .timeSheetOperation("C")
            .timeSheetStatus("20")
            .personWorkAgreementExternalID("ADMINISTRATOR")
            .personWorkAgreement("50000033")
            .companyCode("1010")
            .timeSheetDataFields(TimeSheetDataFields.builder()
                    .timeSheetTaskLevel("NONE")
                    .timeSheetTaskType("ADMI")
                    .recordedHours(new BigDecimal(12))
                    .recordedQuantity(new BigDecimal(12))
                    .timeSheetTaskComponent("WORK")
                    .controllingArea("A000")
                    .hoursUnitOfMeasure("H")
                    .build())
            .build();

    ErpConfigContext erpConfigContext = new ErpConfigContext("S4HANA_CLOUD"); //this is the name of the destination configured in SCP
    TimeSheetEntry savedEntry = new DefaultManageWorkforceTimesheetService().createTimeSheetEntry(entry).execute(erpConfigContext);
}
```

Comment: Hi S.Iovita, thanks for your question. What you describe is a bug, which will be fixed in the next version of SAP S/4HANA Cloud SDK. We'll keep you updated here. Best regards, Florian

Comment: Thank you! Kind regards, Sorin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem of failing *structured field deserialization* has been fixed in the latest version of SAP S/4HANA Cloud SDK. To update, please find the `<dependencyManagement>` in your root Maven POM file and increment the `<version>` for `sdk-bom` to `1.9.2`

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <!-- ... -->

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sap.cloud.s4hana</groupId>
                <artifactId>sdk-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.2</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <!-- ... -->

</project>
```

During compilation Maven will automatically fetch the updated version from the Maven Central Repository. Simply run `mvn clean install` in your local working directory to make sure the new dependencies are propagated to all of your project modules.

Answer (score 0):

Until the problem is patched, you could use a workaround by taking advantage of the OData query builder API and GSON for deserialization.

```java
// use GSON for deserialization steps
final Gson gson = new Gson();

// invoke "toQuery()" to work with OData query builder API
final TimeSheetEntry savedEntry = new DefaultManageWorkforceTimesheetService()
    .createTimeSheetEntry(entry)
    .toQuery()
    .execute(new ErpConfigContext("S4HANA_CLOUD"))
    .as(TimeSheetEntry.class);

// deserialize nested TimeSheetDataFields by reading values from the "custom fields"
savedEntry.setTimeSheetDataFields(
        gson.fromJson(
            gson.toJsonTree(savedEntry.getTimeSheetDataFields().getCustomFields()),
            TimeSheetDataFields.class
        ));

// continue to work with "savedEntry"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Alexander Dümont but now the endpoint responds with : **The endpoint responded with HTTP error code 400. Personnel number 50000141 does not exist or you do not have authorization.** Do you have any idea why this happend? Also I need to mention that using Postman to create such entries with the same payload worked last week and now do not work. I get the same error.

Comment: @S.Iovita - It seems like your target ERP system has changed or removed entity data since the last time it worked for you. I don't see where a parameter for missing "_Personnel number 50000141_" could possibly come from, given your initial question. Using Postman to investigate the problem is already the recommended approach. If this problem persists, please consider creating a separate question. Strategies for finding a solution can be discussed there.